# Determine the number of occurrances of a character regardless of case

Tags: java

I am new to Java & I want to be able to determine the number of occurrances of a character regardless of case. The text is inputted. This is what I have but I was readin by using indexOf its case sensitive and I don't want case sensitive:

```
public int getNumOfOccurrences(String source, String search) {
    int count = 0;
    int prevIndex = 0, curIndex = 0;
    if (source.length() > 0 && search.length()>0) {
        count=-1;
        while (curIndex >= 0) {
            curIndex = source.indexOf(search, prevIndex);
            prevIndex = curIndex + 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do exactly the same as you have now, but call `.ToLowerCase()` on the `source` and `search` parameters before you start the counting. This will, obviously, put everything in lowercase.

Strings are immutable so you'll have to do `String source = source.ToLowerCase()`, or place it in a different variable if you want to keep the distinction.

Comment: What about `search`? What guarantees it to be lower case?

Comment: @PM77-1: I've added it. Feel free to edit it in yourself in the future, it's a correct remark!

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I tried that but I must have not of changed curIndex = source.indexOf(search, prevIndex); to curIndex = sources.indexOf(search, prevIndex);